# Get a single model from server using HTTP in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to retrieve the information of a **single** user from a response sent by a server.

**Get the response :**

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter_project/model/user_model.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' show get;

class PhpUser
{
  PhpUser();


  Future<List<UserModel>> downloadJson() async
  {
    const url = "http://10.0.2.2/TeamMateProject/php/scripts/scriptUser.php";
    final response = await get(Uri.parse(url));
    if(response.statusCode==200)
      {
        List jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
        return jsonResponse.map((e) => UserModel.fromMap(e)).toList();
      }
    else
      {
        throw Exception(response.body);
      }

  }
}
```

I already try to return `Future<UserModel>` instead of `Future<List<UserModel>>`

**Here is how I try to find the user :**

```
FutureBuilder(
      future: PhpUser().downloadJson(),
      builder: (context, snapshot){
        UserModel userModel = snapshot.data as UserModel;
        return ProfileScreen(userModel);
      })
```

**The UserModel :**

```
class UserModel
{
  int idUser;
  String emailUser;
  String pseudoUser;
  String passwordUser;
  String imageUser;
  bool statusUser;
  String lastTimeConnectionUser;

  ///Constructor of the class
  UserModel({ required this.idUser, required this.emailUser, required this.pseudoUser, required this.passwordUser,
    required this.imageUser, required this.statusUser, required this.lastTimeConnectionUser});



  Map<String, dynamic> toMap()
  {
    return {
      'idUser': idUser,
      'emailUser': emailUser,
      'pseudoUser': pseudoUser,
      'passwordUser' :passwordUser,
      'imageUser': imageUser,
      'statusUser': statusUser,
      'lastTimeConnectionUser': lastTimeConnectionUser,
    };
  }

  ///Function to create a UserModel with Json data
  factory UserModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) => UserModel(
      idUser : map['idUser'],
      emailUser : map['emailUser'],
      pseudoUser : map['pseudoUser'],
      passwordUser : map['passwordUser'],
      imageUser : map['imageUser'],
      statusUser : map['statusUser'] == 1,
      lastTimeConnectionUser : map['lastTimeConnectionUser']
  );
}
```

**Here is the response.body :** [{"lastTimeConnectionUser":"2002-02-02 10:00:00"},{"statusUser":0},{"imageUser":"toto.png"},{"passwordUser":"toto"},{"pseudoUser":"Toto"},{"emailUser":"test@gmail.com"},{"idUser":1}]

Of course the UserModel is null, I know I made a mistake but I don't see how to do otherwise

Comment: The server's response almost certainly doesn't look like intended, do you have control over the server's code or can communicate with the developer?

Comment: Hmm it seems that the JSON response from your API is invalid.  Instead of returning a single object, the properties are in array. That's the reason why you cannot parse the JSON and get the user.

Comment: Yes I have the entire control on the server and in fact, in tutos that I watch I return an array. I'll try to return just an instance. I thought it was necessary to return an array of values in order to create the model